# what is data-orig .What it's role? Why it is used for?

Tags: php, html

I am having a PHP page(written by some one else) where all my fields have an attribute named "data-orig" but 2 fields of page not having this property. When I skip these two fields page post back successfully but when I enter some value in these fields(text boxes) then page does not post back successfully. Any help?

Comment: show some code first...

Answer (score 1):

`data-orig` is a custom attribute of HTML5 which is often used to store some data specific to that page.

Example usage:

```
<span id="spanx" data-number="sixty-five">Owl</span>
```

The data-* attributes are used to store custom data private to the page or web application.

These data attributes can be read by the JS included in the page:

an example of reading the data attribute in JQuery is:

```
var theAttributeValue = $('#spanx').attr('data-number'); //gets sixty-five
```

The data-* attributes consist of two parts:

The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"

**Note:**
Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent.

See the example usage below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="someSpan" data-number="676986789">I have a data attribute holding some value</span>
<br/>

Value: <span id="result"></span>
<br/>

<button onClick="getData();">Get The value of Data Attribute</button>

<script>
function getData()
{
  var dataValue = $('#someSpan').attr('data-number');
  $('#result').html(dataValue);
}
</script>
```

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes